# C# Form - MouseClick will click the actual control after losing form focus

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, click, controls

If you ever remove focus from any professional application like Chrome/FireFox/Visual Studio, and then reclick a button/menu item, it will actually click it as if you never lost focus.

How can I apply the same concept in C# WinForm? I tried many things like

```
private void form1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        BringToFront();
        Activate();
    }
```

Activate/focus/select/etc... nothing worked to react the same way, it always takes 3-4 clicks to actually click on a menu!

I thought about making a click event for every single control, but that seemed rather redundant.

[Check this for example (Yellow Clicks)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IV1Kl.gif)

Comment: It's not clear what you want to achieve. Why you want to click on a control on Form even when Form is not having focus?

Comment: Well, the issue is if you Alt+Tab out and Alt+tab back in, you will not be able to click on "Menu Item" from one click, it takes 2 clicks. Now if your entire form is not being focused then you click on a "Menu Item" it will take 3-4 clicks to fire an action.

Comment: I will record a gif and upload it to show what is the issue, i guess my explanation is not good

Comment: @TaW I uploaded and attached to my original post the video

Comment: You are right about menues. (Not buttons though, imo). Try this: `private void menuStrip1_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            menuStrip1.Focus();
        }`

Comment: @TaW That actually worked, I made a MouseEnter function for the main form to focus the main form, then MouseEnter on menustrip to focus the menu strip. which works. Thank you so much Mr.TaW if you would post that as an answer so i can mark it :)

Comment: Done; note the update which goes away from Enter as focus-stealing is not really good behaviour..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right about Menues taking an extra click to get focus.

Which is extra annoying since the menue get highlighted anyway but doesn't react to the 1st click..

You can avoid that by coding the `MouseEnter` event:

```
private void menuStrip1_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // either 
    menuStrip1.Focus();
    // or
    this.Focus();
}
```

The downside of this is, that it is stealing focus from other applications, which is not something a well-behaved application should do..

So I think it is better to wait for a definitive user action; code the `MouseDown` event in a similar way..:

```
private void menuStrip1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    menuStrip1.Focus();
}
```

Or use the event that was made for the occasion:

```
private void menuStrip1_MenuActivate(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    menuStrip1.Focus();
}
```

I can't confirm a similar problem with Buttons or any other controls, though.

Comment: You are right, MouseEnter was causing some funky stuff.. I used menuStrip1_MenuActivate >> menuStrip1.Focus(); && form1_Enter >> this.Focus();

Answer (score 1):

I have find trick to solve your problem. it work for me 100%

See this code:

```
    dynamic elem1;
    private void menuStrip1_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        elem1 = sender;
    }
    private void menuStrip1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        elem1 = null;
    }

    private void Form1_Activated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(elem1 != null){
            elem1.PerformClick();
            if (elem1.GetType().ToString() == "System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem") elem1.ShowDropDown();
        }
        elem1 = null;
    }
```

Here what happend.
When mouse enter button/menu item elem1 = this button/menu, and when mouse leave it set back to null.
so when form Activated we can call elem1.PerformClick() to click the button/menu item.